# Convert T-SQL to Entity SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

I've got a SQL query and need to convert it to Entity SQL for using with `EntityDataSource`. Or at least convert it to LINQ for assigning in `OnQueryCreated` event:

```
SELECT 
    c.[ID], c.[AWB], c.[Location], c.[Datetime1], MAX(c1.Datetime1)
FROM 
    [Customs] c
INNER JOIN
    [Customs] c1 on c1.AWB = c.AWB 
GROUP BY  
    c.[ID], c.[AWB], c.[Location], c.[Datetime1]
ORDER BY
    MAX(c1.Datetime1) DESC
```

I already tried defining `EntityDataSource` like this:

```
<ef:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSourceAWB" runat="server" 
    ContextTypeName="Customs.Data.CustomsModel" EntitySetName="Customs" 
    Select="it.ID,it.Location,it.AWB,it.Datetime1,(select max(c1.Datetime1) from Customs as c1 where c1.AWB = it.AWB) as sorter"
    OrderBy="it.sorter desc" >
</ef:EntityDataSource>
```

but it failed with:

> The ORDER BY sort key(s) type must be order-comparable. Near member
>   access expression..

Comment: it does not has a sorter property.

Comment: Ok, so how to convert this sql to LINQ-expression?

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved by myself. Implemented LINQ-expression in OnQueryCreated:

```
protected void EntityDataSourceAWB_OnQueryCreated(object sender, QueryCreatedEventArgs e)
{
    var orders = e.Query.Cast<MCustoms>();
    e.Query = from c in orders
                where c.isDeleted == 0
                orderby
                    (from c1 in orders
                        where
                            c1.AWB == c.AWB
                        select new
                        {
                            c1.Datetime1
                        }).Max(p => p.Datetime1) descending
                select c;
}
```

Thanks to Mikhail Oumantsev and his Linqer tool.